# How does the Announcer badge work?

Tags: support, publicity-badges

I understand that the Announcer badge can be earned if the question is visited 25 times.

But is this only when I share a link to this question in one of my answers, or can I also share the link (with my user id somewhere to count the accesses) somewhere else, maybe Facebook?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can share the link anywhere, so long as you use the link for questions underneath the question. It does not have to be for your question; you can share the link to any question.

[image]

Comment: thanks now i understand. Is it also possible to ssee how many I referred?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - you could shorten the url using bit.ly, which will then show you how many click-throughs that shortened url gets

Comment: Related: [How this tracking is performed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113638/140951).

Comment: The link must be shared outside the SE network according to [Rebecca's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/158912): `The link must be clicked from outside the network in order for it to count for this purpose.`

Comment: There is no link now, will share do the same?

Comment: It seems sharing the link to an answer (through share link below the answer post) can also earn you `announcer` badge as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268782/does-announcer-badge-count-links-to-answers). Not sure though if it is applicable only on stackoverflow or all the stackexchange communities. In fact @Idolon's answer [below your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131983/318204) also says the same.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's true now, but I believe the question was about sharing links to a SO question outside of SO, so that remains an option.

Comment: @ChrisBallard I see that facts and context got in the way of what could otherwise have been a useful comment. I'll delete it :)

Comment: Have I to share the link on some other site, or do sencing it as email count to?

Answer (score 21):

> > But is this only when I share a link to this quesiton in one of my answer or can I also share the link (with my user id somewhere to count the accesses) somewhere else, maybe facebook?

In order to gain the Announcer badge you **[must](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114608/158912)** share a link outside the SE network. Sharing a link in one of your answer won't work.

Also, rules for the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges [have changed since 2012-01-10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/158912). And sharing direct links to answers now also counts towards these badges.

Comment: What does outside the SE network exactly mean? If I use email to share the link, will it count?

Comment: @convert yes, it will. The link click won't count if the link was placed inside of an answer or question at the StackExchange network sites.