# For what purposes is my user id used when sharing a link?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, sharing

My [user id on StackOverflow is 50776](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776).

I just noticed that when sharing a link, it's appended to the end of any link when I try and get a link for a question/post:

[image: User id attached to share link]

I'm curious what purposes this is for (not being a privacy nut either, I'm not concerned).

The question arises because if I post the link (on a Facebook wall, or tweet it, etc), then *other* people can share that link, and at best, the only tracking that can be done is *who exposed the link for a subset of views*

This is a valid reason in itself, but I was wondering if there were any others.

Comment: Though you're not worried, still related: [Privacy leak in permalink?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's used to track questions views for the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261/booster), and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) badges. There are no other reasons that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you don't want those badges, you can just copy the link to the question from your browser's address bar.

Comment: @KateGregory Or delete the userid from the link before using it anywhere. That way you get the benefit of the shortened link as well.

Comment: See also the blog: [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/). (And @Kate, copying a full link for *an answer* [is slightly harder](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114088/can-we-please-have-an-easy-way-to-get-the-full-url-to-an-answer).)

Comment: And oddly enough, these badges [apparently are not (yet) awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114607/do-shared-link-to-answers-also-count-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges/114608#114608) for answers. That makes the user id in permalinks for answers useless, but I guess that will soon change.

Comment: @Arjan [It has changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/158912) since 2012-01-10: `Sharing direct links to answers now also counts towards these badges`