# How do you find out the ID of a question in the iOS app?

Tags: support, questions, ios-app

How do you find out the ID of a question in the iPhone app of Stack Exchange for iOS 12?

Comment: What you need it  for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the 'Share' link underneath the question, and copy it to the clipboard. Paste it in a text field:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317736/295232
```

The first number is the question ID: 317736 for this one (the other one is your [user ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113638/295232)).

<sub>this answer was brought to you by the Stack Exchange app on iOS 12</sub>

Comment: you mentioned user ID, how can I find mine out?

Comment: Well, from that link. On the website, it's easier; just go to your profile page and it'll be in the URL.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Glorfindel