# Why don't I get the Announcer badge?

Tags: support, badges, publicity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the announcer badge work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78160/how-does-the-announcer-badge-work)

I have linked to a question of mine (namely, [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)), via my link ([Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/871050)), and added a bitly shortener for a shorter URL + tracking clicks (http://bit.ly/phpmsql)

The link (the bitly link) has been clicked 156 times. I find it very (very) hard to believe that it wasn't visited by 25 different IP addresses, especially since I click on it every once in a while and my IP often changes.

So in that case, why don't I get the Announcer badge? Is there something I'm missing? I've read and reread the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page, and the badge description. What am I missing?!

Comment: Maybe SE implemented some ways beyond using IP addresses to determine **unique** visits and correctly discards your repeated visits via your own link?

Comment: @MadScientist: Perhaps, but even without my own visits, there still should have been more than enough. It's very unlikely all 156 clicks are repeated over 6 times...

Comment: Just to be sure, did you bit.ly the full URL or a shorter URL like this: `http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/871050`?

Comment: @jokerdino: [**yes**](http://pokit.org/get/img/a6fd6abf34b329a05e3d20b3c45bbd42.png)

Comment: Perhaps redirects are filtered?

Comment: @hakre: 1. How is that possible, and 2. Why?

Comment: Were you logged into SE when you clicked those links?  I'd say that if the system sees you clicking your own link, it's most likely not going to count it. ;) Total guess... but if I were SE that's what I would do. Also, it has to be 25 unique IP addresses, so it's possible the same group of people clicked your link a total of 156 times.

Comment: @jmort253: I find it hard to believe that less than 25 people clicked that link 7 times each...

Comment: Next question, where did you post this shared link? In some Stack Exchange posts, your blog, Twitter?

Comment: The notorious "Don't use `mysql_*` functions" comment is a good start.  [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @jmort253: ***No***, like I said, I've read and reread that page, and the [meta-faq], and the [meta-tag:faq] entry, I'm asking why am I not getting in on this specific case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're linking these *from* Stack Overflow *to* Stack Overflow, as opposed to some website or blog *outside* the Stack Exchange network *to* the Stack Exchange network.

> @SDC: Please, don't use mysql_* functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the red box? Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi. If you can't decide which, this article will help you. If you pick PDO, here is good tutorial. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO) – Madara Uchiha Oct 22 at 18:11

In short, the goal of this form of link sharing is to bring in traffic from the outside, and only traffic from the outside will count towards the badge. You, my friend, are dealing in blue money, as the links you're referring to are embedded in a comment on a Stack Overflow question. ;)

From [How does the Announcer Badge work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131983/155826):

> In order to gain the Announcer badge you must share a link outside the SE network. Sharing a link in one of your answer won't work.

Comment: Why isn't this documented anywhere? I thought I was working towards that badge, and turns out I wasn't doing anything at all...

Comment: Actually Madara, as long as the links you posted in comments were useful, you may have helped out a lot of people searching for answers. Putting the badge aside, your contributions may have still been helpful. That, to me, is far more important than the badge and is way more meaningful. Hope this helps!

Comment: I meant in the context of the badge, I'm not "spamming" these comments everywhere to get badges, I (and other members of the PHP chat) post them to increase awareness and educate new PHP authors to use correct programming practices. The badge is only an extra.