# Own share links when editing other people's posts in order to increase badge pwnage

Tags: discussion, badges

In the case of the hypothetical user, who likes to collect bright, shiny things, such as the [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer), [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster) and [Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) badges, would it be uncool for them to use their own share links when editing someone else's post that does not already have the relevant link in it?

#### Visual aid for "bright, shiny things":

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156090/why-dont-i-get-the-announcer-badge/156096#156096

Comment: Does not matter unless outside of the SE stack of sites http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64018/how-and-when-does-the-tracking-of-shared-links-work

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll let the hypothetical user know it is safe and fruitless to use own share links :)

Comment: Hey this is my shiny thing! I found it, it's my shiny thing. If you try to take it I may have to eat you!

Comment: It's a yo-yo, you modo!

Comment: **+1** for bright, shiny thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this primarily depends on whether the edit improves the post or not.

When one simply replaces a *working* link to some post with their own share-link to the same post, this is definitely uncool, primarily because such an edit is useless from readers perspective. But as you ask about posts that don't "have the relevant link in it", it's not your case.

When the edit inserts links to posts instead of forum/chat like garbage like "as mentioned by @username", it's a real improvement as it makes it easier for readers to follow the referenced post.

In cases like this, using "own share link" is OK because, well, that's what is shown to the editor under the posts they link to. They sure have a right to "de-personalize" that link by manual removal of their id from the URL *if they want*, but if they prefer not to mess like that, I believe this is totally OK.

---

For adding links to questions it may feel a bit more complicated but it really isn't.

As opposed to answers, questions offer editor an option to pick between the de-personalized link at the *title*, like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197743/own-share-links-when-editing-other-peoples-posts-in-order-to-increase-badge-pwn` and own link at *share*, like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197743/165773`.

But thing to keep in mind here is the same as when adding links to answers. As long as edit improves things *for readers of the post*, it doesn't really matter which of two links were picked. And, conversely, edit that is useless to readers (eg adding link to irrelevant question) would be "uncool" even if editor would use *de-personalized* link.